# arrangement probability

Tags: probability

Question:

I have $5$ yellow bulbs and $4$ red bulbs. These bulbs will be placed in a straight line such that $2$ on the left side are the same colour as each other, and $2$ on the right side are also the same colour (but not the same as the left side). How many ways are there of planting the bulbs?

I'm really not sure about how to answer this question, I assumed you would go about it by doing $5C2 + 5C3$. But I'm really not too sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Choose a color ($2$ ways). Put $2$ bulbs of this color on the right side and $2$ of the other color on the left side. No matter which you choosed, now there are 3 remaining yellow bulbs and 2 remaining red bulbs to be placed in the middle 5 slots. You can do it in $5C2$ ways ($5$ slots with $2$ color choices for each). So in total you have $2\times (5C2)$ ways to complete the whole task.

Comment: Ahh okay, so the answer would be 20 then, right? Thanks a lot!